# Extracting .so files from an archive

Tags: software-installation, archive

I am trying to extact an archive to install an application and it contains .so files and I cannot figure out how to extract them. I have attached screenshots of the files with the particular type as well as the error message that I am given. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: .so refers to shared object, eg. a `file /lib/*.so` shows results like "*ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=...*"

Comment: Have you tried to extract the zip-archive and then run the executable by `./YGO\ Omega.x86_64`?

Comment: @N0rbert It is when I try to extract the archive that I get the error.